# Inconsistent table data scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to extract table data from a table from [this webpage](http://www.espn.com/college-sports/basketball/recruiting/playerrankings/_/view/espnu100/sort/rank/class/2019). However, when I try and extract the table data from each table row, it appears that I am unable to get the data from each row. One pattern that I have detected is that I am unable to see the table data of the rows where there is an image. Is there any other way I can still scrape the data I want (Position, hometown, rank, etc) particularly when it comes to those where the picture is present?

Current code below:

```
# We are unable to get the table data row for individuals that have a picture

rows = soup.find_all('tr')

# This is the data for each table row

for row in rows:
    print(row.text)
```

I have been able to get the player names using the "div" class but I don't think I'll be able to use it for the data in the other columns.

```
# The name of the player is going to be our first column. So let's make a list of the names for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):

name = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'name'})
                    
# Empty list to put our player name in.
players = []
for person in name:
# This line is used to remove the below text that was also included wth the names
    person = person.text.replace("Video | Scouts Report","")
    players.append(person)
                    
# We see that the length of this list is 100. This means that we extraced the names correctly
len(players)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a much easier way would be to read it in a pandas `DataFrame` directly using [`pd.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_html.html), which will immediately return a (length 1) list of all tables from the URL:

```
url = r'http://www.espn.com/college-sports/basketball/recruiting/playerrankings/_/view/espnu100/sort/rank/class/2019'
dfs = pd.read_html(url, header=0)
dfs[0].head()
#   RK                                 PLAYER POS  \
#0   1     James WisemanVideo | Scouts Report   C   
#1   2      Cole AnthonyVideo | Scouts Report  PG   
#2   3  Vernon Carey Jr.Video | Scouts Report   C   
#3   4    Isaiah StewartVideo | Scouts Report   C   
#4   5   Anthony EdwardsVideo | Scouts Report  SG   
#
#                                     HOMETOWN      HT   WT  STARS  GRADE  \
#0                 Memphis, TNEast High School   7'0''  230    NaN     97   
#1               Briarwood, NYOak Hill Academy   6'3''  185    NaN     97   
#2  Southwest Ranches, FLNSU University School  6'10''  275    NaN     97   
#3              Rochester, NYLa Lumiere School   6'9''  245    NaN     97   
#4               Atlanta, GAHoly Spirit School   6'4''  205    NaN     97   
#
#                          SCHOOL  
#0                  MemphisSigned  
#1                           List  
#2        DukeCommitted12/06/2018  
#3  WashingtonCommitted01/20/2019  
#4     GeorgiaCommitted02/11/2019
```

Of course, you will have to do some cleaning, but I think it will be much more efficient than reading everything into lists.

Comment: You mean the HOMETOWN column? I suppose you could easily write something that splits 3 characters after the comma (space + 2 stateinitials).

Comment: I was thinking about player, hometown and schools in particular. But I think I commented too soon as this issue seems to persist across other methods though I guess you have more options for dealing with this with bs4.